# Do pandas dataframes maintain order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing a fairly large dataset stored in essentially one pandas dataframe. I've set up a bunch of preprocessing steps, since I don't need all the information there is and am interested in properties derived from the raw data itself.

The index of the dataframe consists of unique unit ids (not ordered), and in the end I want to calculate things from different sets of units. These subsets are determined from other columns in the dataframe in one of the preprocessing steps.

My problem now is this: The individual units won't matter in the end, so what I want to store after preprocessing ideally is essentially a numpy array, where unit ids are mapped to the row index in the array. However, I also need to know the indices of the different subsets of units. There are quite a lot of them and I don't know which one (or which combination of subsets) will matter, so I don't want to store an array for all the possibilities. Instead I want the row indices of the full numpy array that correspond to the unit ids in the subsets.
Can I rely on the order of the units in the dataframe for that? I.e., is the row in the pandas dataframe of any given index value always the same?

A minimal example would be this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
    'B': [False, True, False, True]}, index=[2, 3, 1, 4])
data.index.names = ['unit_id']

preprocessed_data = data['A'].values
subset = np.flatnonzero(data['B'])
```

Column `'A'` contains the data I want to store eventually (I'm leaving out any preprocessing for simplicity), and column `'B'` signals membership to a subset.

`preprocessed_data` would be the array I'd like to store, and `subset` is a collection of indices (with respect to `preprocessed_data`) that tells me which units are in the subgroup.

I've lost information about the unit ids and basically want to replace using the id by using indices of the output array.
Maybe this is a trivial question but I'm worried I'm missing something.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and desired output. It'll be good to have the code you're using so far. Make sure to give your pandas version.

Comment: I think index in pandas remains the same and maintains the order

Comment: "*I've checked that this is the case with a small example, but I'm worried I'm missing something*" -> can you provide this example?

Comment: Yes, I thought it'd be too trivial but I guess it does clarify things. Maybe the question itself is trivial :)

Comment: @janosch if I understood correctly, **yes**, order is maintained when converting to numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subset` will contains the **positional** indices of the DataFrame that are non-zero in column `B`.

Thus, positions `[1, 3]`, which translate into indices `[3, 4]`:

```
data.index[subset]
# Index([3, 4], dtype='int64', name='unit_id')
```

If you only are about the respective positions of columns `A` and `B` after converting to numpy array: **YES**, the order is conserved. `preprocessed_data[subset]` would give you the values for which the matching `B` is non-zero:

```
preprocessed_data = data['A'].values
subset = np.flatnonzero(data['B'])

preprocessed_data[subset]
```

Output: `array([2., 4.])`

Since you have a boolean in column `B`, note that you could directly use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = data.loc[data['B'], 'A']
```

Or, with [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) in numpy:

```
out = data['A'].to_numpy()[data['B']]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! `preprocessed_data[subset]` is exactly what I want to do in the actual analysis of the preprocessed data.